Remove Default Record Type For Platform Integration User
There's an old account record type on the Platform Integration User profile that I cannot disable:

This record type cannot be deactivated because the following profiles use this record type as default.

I tried all the URL hacking, removing all the record types, and changing the defaults - but to no avail. Any ideas?

Holy mother of God! I found the solution by pure accident just now!
When trying to disable or delete the profile it complains about the Platform Integration User but if I check the id of that link it actually belongs to the Cloud Integration User that I do not even have in my list of available profiles.
This would also explain why the original list complained about the Platform Integration User usage twice as only one of them was correct - the other one had an incorrect label and belonged to the Cloud Integration User. I can't believe that Salesforce would just show me an error that is completely wrong like this.
Anyhoo - when I did the URL hacking as described here I was finally able to change the default and deactivate the profile:
Asset's Record Type can't be deleted because it's used by Identity User profile

It's rare, but these kinds of bugs do happen. Best report it to technical support if you can.

Agreed. It's just a little unfortunate that the bug was triggered on a hidden profile, which didn't help. Why would there be a hidden Cloud Integration User in the first place?

Hidden profiles have been a thing for a long time now. They're meant to ensure the correct permissions for various features (e.g. an integration user). This usually works as designed, but there can be occasional glitches.

I didn't know! Gotta look into this a bit more. Thanks.
